# Drools how to derive smaller readable rules from a big rule

Tags: drools

the facts used by my rule are aggregating other object. The problem I want to solve is a chain of minimum and maximums. Find the group of people(these are facts) having the highest average iq and the lowest age and...and and and..various other criteria.

Look at the rule below, if I would have 2-3 more such criteria the LHS would become unreadable.

How can I do better?

rule "Find thet group with the highest average iq and the lowest average age"
when

```
$options: PeopleGroup(

        $averageIq : getAverageIg(this),

        $averagAge : getAverageAge(this),

)

not (   PeopleGroup(getAverageIg(this) > $averageIq )

        or PeopleGroup(getAverageIg(this) == $averageIq, getAverageAge(this) < $averagAge  )
```

)

then

// add the PeopletGroup to the result

end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem is too vague, but I'll discuss the a couple of options you have anyway.

First, if you are looking for "the best group" you should define a method `PeopleGroup.compareTo( PeopleGroup pg )` so that `PeopleGroup` implements `Comparable<PeopleGroup>`. A rule finding the best group should be simple. (Of course, you have the option of writing any number of static methods comparing two PeopleGroup objects for any kind of ranking you might dream up.) In any case, the rule will be very simple.

```
rule "best group"
when
    $pg1: PeopleGroup()
    not PeopleGroup( this.compareTo( $pg1 ) > 0 )
then
    // $pg1 is best PeopleGroup
end
```

Another approach is to filter facts, either by retracting unqualified facts or by marking them. So, in the first pass, you retract any group that does not have the maximum IQ. Next, you disqualify any remaining group that doesn't have the minimum age. You'll need to order the rules, using agenda-group or salience or additional logic for controlling the order. But the individual rules will be simple.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply!   While I understand the second approach, I do not really get the first one.Based on the example above, the rule above, how would the rule look like with this first approach?

Comment: Added the rule as it could be written with a compareTo.